# Getting java.awt.HeadlessException after run gui tests on Jenkins

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, xvfb

After running gui tests on Jenkins I am getting java.awt.HeadlessException on build Jenkins:

No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.

I am using xvfb in pipeline Jenkins (script), eclipse & maven.

How coud I solve this issue via Jenkins file (script) or maven pom or in another way?

Why am I getting this exception?

Comment: What are you exporting as the DISPLAY variable?

Comment: @JamesHolmes I don't know. What, where and how could I export as the DISPLAY variable ? (If possible, I would like to arrange it in Jenkins file or maven pom)

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your pipeline you probably need to have `export DISPLAY=:0.0` or something similar.

Comment: my jenkins script looks like             wrap([$class: 'Xvfb',  installationName: 'xvfb']) {
                  withEnv(['DISPLAY=:0']) {
                    sh "mvn clean verify -U -B 
                  }                                                                                                                  However this doesn't work. I think that  withEnv(['DISPLAY=:0']) is not correct ?